# What words can replace the conditional words "could" and would"?

Tags: would, could

The words "could" and "would" are very common words in the English Language. However, they are not always the best words to use. I am trying to find better words to replace "could" and "would". Note that it does not need to be a single word. (It can be a complete replacement of the entire sentence).

Examples of sentences with "could" or "would" that may have a better replacement:

I could eat some pie.

If I could check StackExchange, I would be a millionaire.

I would eat some pie.

(Ignore the subject of the sentence. They are completely random).

Comment: Please show us examples of sentences where you think that *could* or *would* are “not the best words”, and tell us why you think this to be the case. In general, strictly grammatical/functional words have no synonyms.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, in OP's defense, "I could eat some pie" really means "I seem to have a medium intensity craving for some pie." Cosmically speaking, anyway.

Comment: Might, may, possibly will.

Comment: Please do answer in the answer section.

Comment: What do you think the meaning of *could* and *would* are? For instance, possible replacements for *I could* include *I'm able to*, *It's possible I can*, and *I'd like to* depending on what you're trying to express. (There might be more.)  It's impossible to give you alternate sentences without knowing what exactly you're trying to say in each case.

Comment: Try a search for "could synonym" or "would synonym".